# what log lib used for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, logging, npm

i meet a issue which is about the logging in nodejs.
I know nodejs provides us the build-in log method, console object for logging. but seems do not support the levels like debug, info, warn, error etc.

I would like a recommended log lib for nodejs which could do those:
1. define log levels;
2. streaming logs;
3. custom format log content;

Thanks for suggestion and help!
cheers.

Comment: probably two most popular choices are bunyan and winston

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the build-in console.log doesn't let you to define levels, also is a bad practice to use console log in production, because of its sync nature.

I love to use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) because of its "trasports". For example it could be a good idea to store your logs inside of an Elasticsearch instance, following the logstash structure, that you will be able to consume using [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), using the [winston-elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-elasticsearch) transporter.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

It is pretty cool and easy to use.